# Can I create a custom image MIME type in Android?

Tags: android, mime, android-mediascanner

My app created a custom .PNG file that's backward compatible with standard .PNG, but I would like my app to be able to recognize my special .PNGs (rather than default to Gallery).  After creating the image, I try to register it with a custom MIME type, but they are still being scanned in as regular PNGs.

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/custom.png");
//now scan the file into the content database
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, new String[] { "image/x-custom" },
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                String mime = cr.getType(uri);
                //mime returns image/png, not image/x-custom :(        
            }
```

Any ideas on how to get Android to recognize my custom MIME type, and/or allow my app to recognize the extended .PNG?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation if you like: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java#l103

Comment: Seems custom mime types are not supported :(

Answer (score 0):

The scan seems to be based on the file extension, i read about that just today, i'm trying to remember where..

Comment: The docs say you can specify optional mimeType for the file. If mimeType is null, then the mimeType will be inferred from the file extension.  I specified a mimeType, so I expect it to be used, not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some activity that registers itself (on the manifest) as capable of handling .png files (or you mime-type). The problem with a custom mime-types of files is that the system should be able to identify your .png as a different type from the regular .png (which it probably won't do). So the best way you can do what you want is to create an IntentFilter that can process all .png's.

You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: That means I'd have to handle viewing of regular .png's as well, not just mine.  Once my activity got called, could I look at the .png, and if it's just a generic one, let another activity handle the VIEW intent?

Comment: Sure, just return false in the onReceive method (means you didn't receive it), or if that doesn't work, just start a new Intent to VIEW the file.

Comment: I think onReceive is only for Broadcasts, I don't think intents to view an image are broadcast, are they?  Starting a new Intent could work, but if my activity is set as the default one for .pngs, won't that just start my activity again and do an infinite recursion?

Comment: Well, you can't prevent the Gallery from viewing png's. You can also change the extension of your own png's to something else... probably that will help. And yes, that would start a recursive loop :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to　add　your　mimetype and file extension　to　**android/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java.**

When mediascanner can't find your mimetype in MediaFile.java, it will get a new mimetype for it by basing on the file extension.